# Heroku login and logout does not work?

Tags: heroku, helper

My account on heroku is suspended, and I am trying delete it on "cmd or git bash"; however, in my program, I cannot logout from that account.

This is the error I receive:

```
$ heroku logout
C:/Users/Romantiku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:30:in `rescue in start': und
efined method `styled_error' for Heroku::CLI:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/Romantiku/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:16:in `start'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: My account isn't suspended and I get this same error when doing `heroku status`.  I just recently updated and the heroku toolbelt version is reported as `heroku-gem/2.30.3 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.2`

Answer (score 11):

I just logged in again as another account.

This handled logging out as I did not see a clear cut way from the command line on how to logout

```
heroku login
Email: new@email.account
Password: ******
```

Comment: you can try heroku logout

Answer (score 2):

Hit the command "**heroku logout**" from you cli terminal.

If the error persists clear your browser cache. So that you can login again. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `heroku login -i` to login with your email and password from the cli instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only need to uninstall heroku cli and install it,but it didn't fix it, I then ran the login command with sudo.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g heroku-cli
sudo npm i -g heroku
sudo heroku login
```